# Is it safe to reuse a deleted branch's name?

Tags: svn, branch

For example:

1. I create a branch named refactor.
2. I reintegrate the branch to the trunk.
3. I delete the branch.

**Is it safe to repeat the process with another branch named refactor?**

Answer (score 3, accepted):

With SVN the only problem you might run into is that when merging the `mergeinfo` property of the merge point (folder or file depending on the level where the merge was made) will contain the branch name and revision numbers of previous merges. I don't think that SVN actually uses this information when merging, but it becomes confusing sometimes as a user.

If you don't care about this then it should work fine ... but I know in previous projects we used `mergeinfo` as an indication of what branches we had merged back into trunk, so re-using a branch name would be dangerous.

Answer (score 1):

Yes, you can do this, as long as you're not confused about which refactor is which when you look at the Subversion log history.

Assuming you have some sort of trouble ticket system, it would be better to tie particular revisions to the trouble ticket that caused the revision to be made, either by number or code.

Answer (score 1):

This shouldn't be an issue -- except for one tiny thing...

Even though that branch has the same name as the old branch, as far as Subversion is concerned, it is a completely new branch. If you look at the `svn log` of the branch, it won't trace itself back to the original branch with that name. The old branch won't even be considered part of the merge history. It's a completely different branch that just happens to have the name name.

In this case, this is exactly what you want. However it can cause some confusion. One of the biggest issues I've hit is someone who deleted a file or directory and then added it back in  is **shocked! shocked!** that Subversion's merge isn't working as expected.

As long as you understand this, everything should be just fine.

Answer (score 0):

Yes, it's totally OK.

You can find everything in [SVNBook](http://svnbook.red-bean.com/en/1.7/svn.branchmerge.html).